# How to check if row is deleted in express-cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, express-cassandra

I have the following service:

```
    const searchByQuery = {
        channelId: channelId,
        id: models.timeuuidFromString(messageId),
    }
    const deleteMessage = util.promisify(models.instance.MessageStore.delete).bind(models.instance.MessageStore);
    const deletedMessage = await deleteMessage(searchByQuery);
    console.log(deletedMessage)
    return "Message Deleted"
}
```

I want to check if deletion was successful. But deletedMessage always returns the following:

```
ResultSet {
  info: {
    queriedHost: '127.0.0.1:9042',
    triedHosts: { '127.0.0.1:9042': null },
    speculativeExecutions: 0,
    achievedConsistency: 1,
    traceId: undefined,
    warnings: undefined,
    customPayload: undefined,
    isSchemaInAgreement: true
  },
  rows: undefined,
  rowLength: undefined,
  columns: null,
  pageState: null,
  nextPage: undefined,
  nextPageAsync: undefined
}
```

This is returned even if the data doesnot exist (i.e. deletion did not happen).

I have tried searching for it in docs as well and also tried after_delete hook but to no avail.